# HTML - Hiding div in iframe from SSRS site

Tags: html, css, iframe, reporting-services

I want to have SSRS site in my another site on the same localhost. I use for it iframe. This is code with it:

```
<article>
        <div id="framed-application" style="overflow:hidden;">
            <iframe src=@Model.allSSRS.FirstOrDefault().link >
            </iframe>
        </div>
</article>
```

(I read link from my database.)

CSS:

```
iframe{
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    /*margin-top: -2.5%;*/
    border: 0;
}
```

But there is sth like `<div class="ToolBarButtonsCell>` on this site, which I don't want to see. Can I hide this? If yes - how to do that?
This is how div looks like:
[image: SSRS bar menu]

I tried to use `margin-top` but many computers have different resolution, so not always everything is hide (or if I change my browser window size).

Thanks for any help.
Monica

Comment: you can't edit iframe content.

Comment: So then I think I should use somehow `margin-top`. But how fit it to browser window size or computer's resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rc:Toolbar=false` hides the toolbar. If the value of this parameter is false, all remaining options are ignored. If you omit this parameter, the toolbar is automatically displayed for rendering formats that support it. The default of this parameter is true.

You can hide the toolbar in Report Server by URL as below:

```
http://<ServerName>/reportserver?/Sales/YearlySalesSummary&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=HTML4.0&rc:Toolbar=false
```

Please refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx) for more details.